# How can I prevent session errors with older versions of firefox?

Tags: session, mozilla

Everytime someone has an issue with sessions on our site I have a log track where, when, what, who. Every issue we've had with sessions not holding are mozilla 4.0 or 5.0.

Example Issue:

```
Account ID: 14901 
IP: *********
Browser: Mozilla 
Browser Version: 5.0 
Possible Issue Occured: 12/03/2014 03:02:07 

URL: http://**************/question-answer

Most Recent Session Data:
```

As you can see the session data is blank and not holding anything. Is this a known issue with these versions of Mozilla? Is there some sort of session limit or something?

Update, Background And Additional Information:

We provide our users with exams that they can take on their account to save their progress. Nothing is getting saved to the database other than default values.

Now this issue is not common and our IT group has never been able to replicate it. We created a log so that whenever this issue arises it tracks this information so we can get a better idea of what people were doing and using to get the error.

It does track versions correctly, I've tried mozilla 5.0.1.0 and had no problems. I forced it to be an error and the Browser Version showed as : 5.0.1

I do not believe this is a case of someone leaving the browser open and idle for an extended period of time. We have been on the phone with customers and had them start new exams that were having this issue and it continued having the issue until we had them reset everything in their browser.

Comment: I think whoever put that report together just looked at the user agent. "Mozilla/5.0 is the general token that says the browser is Mozilla compatible, and is common to almost every browser today." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Gecko_user_agent_string_reference

Comment: how is precisely the session not holded, do you have more info on based on what you gather those issues and why you had the necessity to keep those logs? (maybe it's a bug in your code..)

Comment: I also think that the issue is simply that someone left the page open for several hours or days then came back and clicked a link. The server had long since discarded the session as unused.

Comment: Please see updates, I tried to respond to both of you.